# CORBA: Java's servertool does not allow me to register a server class

Tags: java, corba, persistent

Have been pulled down into the realm of CORBA...

I am trying to quickly learn (if not master...) CORBA along side its Java mappings. I have come upon some old tutorials:

[Java IDL: The "Hello World" Example](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/jidlExample.html)

[Naming Service](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/jidlNaming.html)

[orbd - The Object Request Broker Daemon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html)

I have created a project with the source from the first link above (Java IDL...) and have run both HelloServer and HelloClient after running the following command:

```
start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

Not surprisingly, everything works :)

**I then with to register the HelloServer in the as a persistent service and fail miserably!**

I run the following command (launched from the "bin" folder (that which contains the .class files)):

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\servertool -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

I then run:

```
servertool > register -server HelloServer -classpath .
```

and the process simply hangs...

What might I be doing wrong

Comment: Just to clarify, "servertool > " is the prompt in the servertool command shell, and you type "register -server HelloServer -classpath ." in the command shell. The examples also include a "-applicationName HelloServerApName" argument.

Comment: You're right, but they don't change the outcome - that is I get the same hang whether or not I add them, and moreover it is my understanding that they are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not sure why things have started to work but...

From the "bin" folder (that which contains the .class files) I have run:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

Then opened a new cmd shell (from the same location) - since the previous one is running the orbd and have run:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\servertool -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

Both:

```
register -server HelloServer -classpath . -applicationName HelloServerApName
```

and

```
register -server HelloServer -classpath .
```

***work***

Comment: Do you know WHY using the absolute path works? and not just simply running orbd or servertool from the cmd line in the directory where your server is (which the operating system will found in the PATH)?

Comment: For me it only works in a Linux environment, I tried running the application on a Windows XP SP3 with latest Java JDK 7 installed and I get "Bad server definition: main class not found" although I ran the servertool using absolute path and from the same directory where the .class files for the persistent server are. Do you know how to specify more than one path after the -classpath parameter? In Linux I did "-classpath .:../otherdir" and it worked but on Windows it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I got it working in Windows also I did the following: 0) Made sure the JDK path has no spaces (I deinstalled Java from C:\Program Files\Java and installed it to C:\Java) 1) Created an environment variable %JAVA_HOME% with the value of C:\Java and then appended to PATH variable %JAVA_HOME\bin 2) From a cmd ran with or without abs path %JAVA_HOME%\bin\servertool -ORBInitialPort 1050
3) %JAVA_HOME%\bin\servertool -ORBInitialPort 1050
4) Inside servertool entered: register -server PersistentServer -classpath .;..\otherdir 5) java -cp .;..\otherdir PersistentClient (otherdir was generated by idlj)

Comment: What I think is the problem is that you have to make sure your Java JDK or JRE installation path does NOT contain spaces! This is very important as I found out on Windows it will not work unless your Java is installed in a directory without spaces.

Comment: @ReturnInfinity did you try using windows 8.3 notation (short) paths? [for instance: PROGRA~1\java\JDK16~1.0_2]

Comment: Haven't tried that, will have to look into it. It will most probably work. Thanks for the suggestion. But the thing is that the servertool works without specifying an absolute path if the path where servertool and/or orbd is installed doesn't contain spaces. That means I only have to append to PATH variable the location of %JAVA_HOME%\bin and then simply run servertool/orbd from the directory where I happen to be and it will work. (assuming Java has been installed to a directory without spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Does HelloServer know where (port and machine name) to find the Naming Service?

If not, this link might help: [orbd - The Object Request Broker Daemon (ORBD)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html#starting).